# Is it possible to use the base class constructor to initialize values to base class private members using derived class?

Tags: c++

What I would like to do is set the `width` and the `height` variables of the `Shape` class using the `Rectangle` class.

Shape.h

```
class Shape
{
    public:
        Shape(int x, int y);
    private:
        int width;
        int height;
};
```

Shape.cpp

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y): width(x), height(y)
{
}
```

Rectangle.h

```
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
    public:
        Rectangle(int, int);
};
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int x, int y):Shape(x, y)
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Rectangle rec(10,7);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is use the `rec` object to initialize the `width` and `height` variables of the class `Shape` which are private. Is there any way to do that? Or do I need to set the `width` and `height` variables to protected?

Comment: You already do that in your code. You can't print it like that though, since it's `private`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I get an error when I do that. `error: 'int Shape::width' is private`. Sorry about the print statement. I just realized that.

Comment: @royK the code you have posted (after that edit) is correct and doesn't generate any errors

Comment: No you cant acess private member in derived class, either declare them as protected or write public API as a setter function

Comment: I am getting the same error even when I remove that line. I am using CodeBlocks. Is that a possible problem with the software?

Comment: @royK Then please show us on which line exactly the error is.

Comment: @royK - no it isn't a problem with CodeBlocks, it just calls whatever the configured compiler is (generally mingw or tdm-mingw) which are both `gcc`. Now there may be compiler options that will influence the c++ standard you are using, but CodeBlocks works just fine.

Comment: Sorry about that. I checked the code and I had another function that was trying to access the private members that I forgot to comment out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would `Shape` have members `width` and `height` when they only make sense for a `Rectangle`?

Comment: @Walter they would make sense if I have several shapes (triangle, square, etc.). I can directly inherit those variable without creating a separate variable for each shape. Nevertheless, I was just testing out an example to understand inheritance. It's simply for practice.

Comment: No, they don't make sense, in particular if you have several shapes (it seems you failed to grasp the idea of polymorphism). For a circle, for example, the natural parameter is its radius, not a width and a height. You need a member function `virtual int width() const=0;` which is then overridden in the derived class implementing the actual shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already compiles fine except for you cannot have access to `rec.height` in your main function as it is private.

A derived class inherited publically have access to the public constructor of the based class.

```
int main()
{
    Rectangle rec(10,7);
    // cout << rec.height << endl;  <----------- disabled
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I just realized it. I am using CodeBlocks. Where exactly did you compile the code?

Comment: @royK, used `gcc` compiler (g++) on `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation of `Rectangle` correctly calls the base constructor using its parameters. Using modern C++ (at least C++11) the implementation of `Rectangle` can be simplified by using [*inheriting constructors*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors):

```
struct Rectangle : public Shape {
    using Shape::Shape;
};
```

To access the `private` member, it needs to either be changed to `public`, or you need to implement a getter method in the base class. Alternatively you can make the `private` member `protected` and implement the getter in the derived class (although, as `height` is common to all derived classes, it would be appropriate to place the getter in the base class).

```
class Shape {
/* ... */
public:
    int get_height() const { return height; }
};
```

```
std::cout << rec.get_height() << std::endl;
```